# java.io.FileNotFoundException for no reason?

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

So, I'm VERY new to programming. I've been following the android course for 4 days now, and I'm having LOTS of troubles with Android Studio, problems with no apparent cause. The program worked fine one day, but as soon as I woke up the next day and try to learn more, some random error appears and won't let me proceed.

In this case the problem isn't as bad. i can still see the app preview, and apparently the coding has no problem, but I get the following error.

```
Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\cascascap\AndroidStudioProjects\Justjavaparapobres\.gradle\2.8\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
> C:\Users\cascascap\AndroidStudioProjects\Justjavaparapobres\.gradle\2.8\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
```

(Sorry for the spanish parts. That's my native language.)

I can still program, but I can't run the app on my cellphone. I followed the course perfectly and even experimented myself so I kind of know what I'm doing. The only thing I changed is programming the app for Gingerbread instead of Icecream Sandwich (since it's the only cellphone I have), but i
I'm still attacked by random errors.

As I said, this is not the first time I'm troubled by an error, but I was able to find solutions to the previous ones thanks to this page.

How can I solve this problem?
Is there a way to prevent it from happening again? Since I have the feeling, I will just get another error in the next day.

Sorry for the long post, and thank you for the ones who always take time to answer those in need of knowledge.

Comment: try  File->invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Sadly that does not work, that was the solutions to one of my previous problems so i tried trying it out this time too, with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close Android Studio and then remove .gradle folder in the following path

```
C:\Users\cascascap\AndroidStudioProjects\Justjavaparapobres\
```

Open your project and clean & rebuild it.

Comment: That worked, thank you a lot. Sadly i still not know why the error ocurred int he first place, but at least i can still learning now.